# Electron + Jest - ipcRenderer is undefined in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, electron, jestjs

I am contributing to a project which is built with React (with webpack) running in Electron. When executing **unit tests with Jest**, it fails with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` (and works fine when not testing, eg. run with Electron).

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer } from  'electron';
// some more imports

class Setup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // some state
    };

    ipcRenderer.on('open-file-reply', this.someMethod); // << fails on this line
  }
  // more class stuff
}
```

Comment: I've tried many different solutions including adding Webpack's "target": "electron" or  "target": "electron-renderer" but non of these worked

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It took me a few days but finally, I found this answer in [this great blog post](https://www.jamestease.co.uk/blether/mock-es6-imports-with-jest). Quote:

> Jest is called from Node and doesn't run test code through Webpack.
>   Instead, we have to use Jest's mocking functions to replace the import
>   with a stub file.

Jest has a helper method called `moduleNameMapper [object<string, string>]` . From jest documentation:

> A map from regular expressions to module names that allow to stub out
>   resources, like images or styles with a single module.

It should be added in your **package.json** root object like this:

```
{
  "name": "My awesome app",
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "electron": "<rootDir>/src/components/tests/mock/electron.js"
    }
  }
}
```

and the mock file itself (/src/components/tests/mock/electron.js):

```
export const ipcRenderer = {
  on: jest.fn()
};
```

This way you can stub other electron modules and methods (like remote which is shown in the blog above).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is creating an `electron.js` file in `__mocks__` in your root folder.

The electron.js should look something like

```
export const ipcRenderer = {
  on: jest.fn(),
};
```

You can read more at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules

Comment: I think menu is mocked in a same way, but if I'm using menu of electron in renderer to create context menus.It is throwing errors.
error ->   Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Menu is not a constructor
Can you help in this.